# How to check element exists and take it's content in single expression in Geb/Groovy?

Tags: groovy, geb

I have a table which elements can be either just text of in normal mode or input fields if in an edit mode.

Currently I am finding data with the following code (see `firstName`):

```
class UserRow extends Module {

    static content = {

        cell { i -> $("td", i) }

        id {
            cell(0)
        }

...
        firstName {

            if( cell(2).find("input").length ) {
                cell(2).find("input")
            }
            else {
                cell(2)
            }

        }
```

Isn't it possible to do this in single expression in Groovy?

Comment: Maybe: `cell(2).$('input') ?: cell(2)` not tried it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim seems to suggest a very good solution in his comment:

`cell(2).$('input') ?: cell(2)`

This will work because `AbstractNavigator` [implements `asBoolean()`](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/fa05c94f114ffdff4c74f6348ff6e7c11cbd3d95/module/geb-core/src/main/groovy/geb/navigator/AbstractNavigator.groovy#L58) and thus empty navigators (navigators which don't match any elements) evaluate to false in boolean expressions.